# React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally, in supposedly simple get-display-retrieve inputs component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

Please help,
I am going around in circles (new to React).
I either get 'React Hook "useState" is called conditionally' and if I change it to be the beneath code,
I get 'React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally'.

The idea is to

1. retrieve the data via useQuery and the db record id pased in via props.
2. if that data is null, e.g. the query used the id=0 (like an insert not an update of a record), then deviceObject to  the empty record, else to the retrieved data.
3. Set 'deviceObject' into state.

i.e. The order is important, but setRow should only be called once, not multiple times, which leads to react crashing with too many renders.

```
export default function DeviceModal(props) {
    const dataRowId = props.dataRowId;
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [row, setRow] = useState('')

    const device = useQuery(getDevice_query, {variables: {id: dataRowId}});
    if (device.loading) return <DataLoader/>;
    if (device.error) return <p style={{color: 'white'}}>{("GraphQL Error " + device.error)})</p>;

// Create an empty recordObject to be populated and sent back for insert to db.
    const emptyDevice = {
        id : 0,
        deviceId : 0,
        deviceClass :{name : '',},
        serialNumber: 0,
    }

    const deviceObject = device.data.getDevice !== null ? device.data.getDevice : emptyDevice;

    useEffect(()=>{
        setRow(deviceObject)
    },[])


    const handleSave = (value) => {
    };

    const HandleChange = e => {
        useEffect(()=>{
          setRow({...row, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    },[])
};

return (
    <div>
        <Modal ...>
         <div className={classes.paper}>
               <Grid container direction="row" justify="center"  alignItems="center">
                   <Grid item xs={4}>
                        <TextField
                            id="deviceId"
                            name="deviceId"
                            defaultValue={row.deviceId}
                            onChange={HandleChange}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                {/* 30 other  textfields to capture*/}
                    ....
           </div>
        </Modal>
    </div>
)};

Edit as per Long Nguyen:

// Set the device object record to be either the empty record, or the records retrieved from db if those are populated (not null)    
let deviceObject = {};

const Component = () => {
    deviceObject = device.data.getDevice !== null ? device.data.getDevice: emptyDevice;
    return <RefactorComponent />;
}
   // Set the device object (empty or populated with db-retrieved rows,) into state
const RefactorComponent = () =>
{
     useEffect(()=>{
          setRow(deviceObject)
      },[deviceObject])
   // return ()
}
Component();
```

Comment: You can only put useEffect directly inside of a component function. You can not put it in HandleChange.

Comment: If you only want setRow({...row, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }) to happen when HandleChange occurs, then just put it directly within HandleChange and get rid of the useEffect that it is currently inside.

Comment: I have removed it from 'HandleChange', but I get React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally, ..on the top and remaining useEffect   and  if I remove that useEffect leving only setRow(deviceObject), I get Too many re-renders.

Comment: I must be blind. I didn't see that you actually did a conditional return above your useEffect. You can absolutely not use the useEffect function after potentially doing a return for the whole component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a call of hooks after condition. It makes the hook that you call does not appear in the same order between renders, because “React relies on the order in which Hooks are called”.

You can find useful information, also the way to solve your problem in this document.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation

UPDATE:

- You should not place hooks in a handle, of course.
- If you still want to keep the original code, you can extract the block after condition to the other component like this

```js
const Component = () => {
  if(conditions) return <Other />
  //  bad, this hook order is not fixed
  // it can appear or not
  useEffect(() => {
    ...the effect after condition...
  });

  return (...);
}

const Component = () => {
  if(conditions) return <Other />
  return <RefactorComponent />
}

const RefactorComponent = () => {
  // ✅ ok, the hooks order is fixed
  useEffect(() => {
    ...the effect after condition...
  });

  return (...);
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question to make the required logic clearer after reading thru the suggested information.